# Image upload and resize

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Application allows users to choose a photo (PhotoChooserTask) or take it (Launcher). It's easy, I got it. But then, I have to upload this photo to my server (PHP on server side  only). And that's my problem. Now I'm doing it via RAW POST (POST body), but it's not a good solution. I'd want to resize choosen photos (i.g. to 1024x768) and upload them to my server and save to the file. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure you do not want the server to resize it. Keep in mind someone may want to exploit your application and may upload an "unexpected image", which could brake the layout. (Additional Hint)

Comment: @Rolice I want to resize photos on the device to make their size smaller

Answer (score 0):

There's SaveJpeg function in WriteableBitmap that allows you to specify the necessary parameters of a file such as width, height, quality etc. You could save the bitmap in different resolution (to a memory stream for example) and then send the resulting byte array to the server.

Please, see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/resizing-images-in-windows-phone-7.aspx) article for reference.

Answer (score 0):

To resize the photo, use [DecodeJpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708027%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and pass the stream and the size (1024, 1024 in your case). You will get a `WriteableBitmap` which you can then turn back into a jpeg stream by using [Extensions.SaveJpeg()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: Okey, thanks. It works :). But still don't know, how to upload a photo to my server...

Comment: If POST is still not good enough for you, you should probably ask the question with a PHP tag assigned to it (and then use WebClient.UploadString() or UploadStream() to upload the file via PUT.